# How to allow numeric as well as decimal number in infopath optional field

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have few infopath optional field those data type is "Double". These fields are not mandatory. If user wants, he/she should be able to enter complete number or number with decimal both should accept otherwise should be empty. Using the below 
custom pattern matching trying to validate, but in this case field is becoming mandatory. How can I do this?

```
\d+\.\d\d
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more condition with this `Field is not blank` and `Field does not Match pattern \d+\.\d\d`

Shows the validation